# Using multiple DbContext getting error Cannot use multiple DbContext instances within a single query execution

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I started a new MVC app using .NET Core 3.  I have three DbContext files that use three different databases: ComplaintDbContext for my main application, IdentityCoreDbContext for Identity users, and EmployeeDbContext for my employee database.

In my app I have a repository class called ComplaintRepository and the constructor looks like this:

```
public ComplaintRepository(ComplaintDbContext context, 
        EmployeeDbContext employeeContext)
    {
        _context = context;
        _employeeContext = employeeContext;
    }
```

In my ComplaintController I need to get data from both databases.  I can get my data from my Complaint database, but once I call my Action that gets data from my Employee database I get the error:

Cannot use multiple DbContext instances within a single query execution. Ensure the query uses a single context instance.

I tried something like this:

```
public class FrameworkContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class ExtendedContext : FrameworkContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

I cannot get it working.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Edit:

I started a new repository called EmployeeRepository to separate concerns.  Here is my Action that is giving me problems:

```
    public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> GetWorkerList()
    {
        var employees = _employeeRepository.GetEmployeesByUnit(22);

        //Get ApplicationUsers where user exists in Employees list
        IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> userList = _userManager.Users
            .Where(emp => employees.Any(e => emp.EmployeeID == e.EmployeeId)).OrderBy(e => e.LastName);

        return userList;            
    }
```

My Employee database and my Identity database both share a column called EmployeeId.

When I tried changing it to use ToList() I started getting a different error:

InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'Where( source: DbSet, predicate: (a) => Any( source: (Unhandled parameter: __employees_0), predicate: (e) => a.EmployeeID == e.EmployeeId))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

Edit:

I used Tao Zhou's recommendation of using ToList() and I was able to get it working.  I replaced IEnumerable in my repository to use this:

```
    public List<TblEmployee> GetEmployeesByUnit(int unitId)
    {
        var emp = _context.TblEmployee.Where(e => e.UnitId == unitId &&
                e.TermDate == null)
            .OrderBy(e => e.LastName).ToList();

        return emp;
    }
```

In my controller I basically did the same and I now have this:

```
    public List<ApplicationUser> GetWorkerList()
    {
        var employees = _employeeRepository.GetEmployeesByUnit(22);

        List<ApplicationUser> userList = new List<ApplicationUser>();

        //Get ApplicationUsers where user exists in Employees list
        foreach (TblEmployee emp in employees)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = _userManager.Users
                .Where(e => e.EmployeeID == emp.EmployeeId).FirstOrDefault();

            userList.Add(user);
        }

        return userList;            
    }
```

I would like to use LINQ instead of the foreach loop.

Comment: You say you are using three different _databases_, but then refer to three different DbContexts. Do those DbContexts map to the same SQL database?

Comment: Share us your query code. You could not combine `ComplaintDbContext ` and `EmployeeDbContext` in the same query, try to query from them with `ToList()` and then query from the list result.

Comment: CPerson, the three DbContexts do NOT map to the same database.  I have three different databases on the same SQL server that I am using.  Thanks.

Comment: Tao Zhou, I tried using ToList() and I am getting a different error now.  Please see my edit.  Thank you.

Comment: What about `_userManager.Users
            .Where(emp => employees.Any(e => emp.EmployeeID == e.EmployeeId)).OrderBy(e => e.LastName).ToList()`?

Comment: Tao Zhou, I tried that code and I get the error: 'Where<ApplicationUser>(
    source: DbSet<ApplicationUser>, 
    predicate: (a) => Any<TblEmployee>(
        source: (Unhandled parameter: __employees_0), 
        predicate: (e) => a.EmployeeID == e.EmployeeId))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem, from what I could tell, you cannot use different DbContext for same query. Just make sure you used same DbContext object for same query.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only using the `EmployeeId` in the `Any` method comparison, you could use `Contains`

```cs
var employees = _employeeRepository.GetEmployeesByUnit(22);
var employeeIds = employees.Select(x => x.EmployeeId).ToHashSet();

//Get ApplicationUsers where user exists in Employees list
IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> userList = _userManager.Users
            .Where(emp => employeeIds.Contains(emp.EmployeeID)).OrderBy(e => e.LastName);

return userList;
// or return userList.ToList();
```